# Making cocoa draw(_ dirtyRect) respond to needsDisplay sent from different class

Tags: swift, cocoa

I have a macOS Swift app with two Views. One is a Metal MTKView which draws an animated 3D set of objects and the second is a graph which is drawn using a BezierPath. The Metal view controller class is called GameViewController and the Metal drawing is done in its delegate called Renderer. The graph is done in an instance of the class GraphView and is connected to the GameViewController using an outlet, called "graph". Here is an outline of the code:

```
class GameViewController: NSViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var graph: GraphView!
 
     @IBAction func h1_Slider(_ sender: NSSlider) {
        h1_length = sender.floatValue       
       dodraw()                 // This is only here to make a point about - it is not used normally
    }

    func dodraw() {
        graph.needsDisplay = true
        return
    }

<lots of other stuff to set up Metal drawing>

}

class Renderer: NSObject, MTKViewDelegate {

    public var graphRef = GameViewController()      //. Allows access to GameViewController from elsewhere

<lots of stuff to set up Metal>

   func draw(in view: MTKView) {    // Metal drawing loop
    
    grafRef.dodraw()        // this is supposed to cause GraphView to update its drawing
 
 <this is where the Metal drawing is done>
 
 }
} 

class GraphView:NSView
 {
    
    override func draw(_ dirtyRect:CGRect) {
        
        <This is where the Bezier drawing takes place in a View in the Storyboard View identified as an instance of GraphView
        
    }
    
 }
```

Both drawing components work well individually. I would like to connect them.

Basically, the inner loop of the Metal drawing, which occurs 60 times a second, calls the dodraw() method in the GameViewController via the reference graphRef. This should set the needsDisplay Bool to true in GraphView so that the graph can be drawn. Instead I get "Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while implicitly unwrapping an Optional value" with the graph underlined in red. I also get in the Xcode output window: "[Nib Loading] Failed to connect (controller) outlet from (Vectors.GameViewController) to (MTKView): missing setter or instance variable"

If I replace the "needsDisplay = true" in the dodraw() method with a print("Q") and do nothing else, the letter Q is printed many times in the output window of Xcode. This shows that the graphRef link in Renderer is working fine. Likewise, if I put back the "graph.needsDisplay = true" and remove the dodraw() call in the Metal drawing loop, the graph is displayed while I move the slider in the GameViewController class. This shows that there seems to be no trouble with the "graph.needsDisplay = true" statement and that graph.needsDisplay is not nil.

I consider this to be a very strange behavior: I seem to have no trouble invoking the needsDisplay = true command by appending a "graph." before it and I have no trouble referring to the dodraw() method from the Metal inner loop. The only trouble is I can't do these at the same time. What is going wrong? Is it a misconception about how Swift works?

Comment: Have you double checked the connection of the outlets in the xib/storyboard? Any missing connections or connections to non-existent outlets?

Comment: Yes, I checked multiple times. Right clicking on the view in the storyboard shows only one connection and it is the correct one. Also, my test using the slider showed that invoking dodraw() was successfully reaching the draw function in Graphview.

Comment: Post a [mre] please. What's in the storyboard and how are `GameViewController`, `Renderer` and `GraphView` instantiated?

Comment: It is a rather complicated program - I can try to generate a minimal example which exhibits the problem. Since the program is not being sold, I could post a zip file of the entire project (it is a 3D visualization of nuclear magnetic resonance displaying rotating vectors and a number of magnetic fields).  The storyboard has a custom view which is an instance of GraphView. This is situated on the MTKView which is instantiated via the line "guard let mtkView = self.view as? MTKView" in GameViewController (in ViewDidLoad). In that latter class an instance of Renderer (called renderer) is created.

Comment: Here is a conundrum. I placed the statement "print(#function, "graph =", graph)" just before the "needsDisplay" line in dodraw(). If I only call dodraw from the slider, I get the result: "dodraw() graph = Optional(<Vectors.GraphView: 0x1221256c0>)" and the graph is updated normally. If I place the dodraw call in the Renderer loop, I get "dodraw() graph = nil". Same function, different result for graph when dodraw is called from the two different places. Interesting!

Comment: Is `public var graphRef = GameViewController()` the only `GameViewController` or an extra `GameViewController`?

Comment: I believe that is the only instantiation of GameViewController. It is intended as a reference. I took the Metal part of the app from a web tutorial which displays a 3D box with lighting, etc. I replaced the vertices with those generated by another func which displays a number of 3D vectors which rotate in a way which demonstrates nmr. This part works very well.

Comment: Since I am calling dodraw() using the reference "graphRef", which refers to an instance of GameViewController, is it possible that the instance is not respecting the definition of graph in the @IBOutlet? How do I get around this if so? Thanks!!

Comment: I think you have two `GameViewController`s. `Renderer.graphRef` should point to the original `GameViewController`.

Comment: The controller for the single window used by the app is a GameViewController. So, the graphRef is another instance. Renderer.graphRef is not recognized as a valid. When I use Renderer.graphRef.dodraw() in the renderer draw() method I get: "Instance member 'graphRef' cannot be used on type 'Renderer'; did you mean to use a value of this type instead?"

Comment: I mean something like `var renderer = Renderer(); renderer. graphRef = alreadyExistingGameViewController`.

Comment: How do I reference the "already existing" GameViewController. If I just use GameViewController, renderer.graphRef evaluates to nil.

Comment: In methods of `GameViewController` the reference is `self`.

Comment: I am afraid none of these suggestions worked for various reasons. I also tried to make a protocol called "link" which had the method name (dodraw() - I didn't make it static). I then added the line "var delegate link!" to Renderer and tried to invoke dodraw() in the drawing func using self.delegate!.dodraw(). This didn't work either, as self.delegate evaluated as nil. Of course I added the "link" protocol to the GameViewController class. Any ideas?

Comment: Are `graphRef` and `grafRef` the same property?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`public var graphRef = GameViewController()` creates a new `GameViewController`. To make `graphRef` a reference to the existing `GameViewController` from the storyboard, add a `graphRef` parameter to `Renderer.init` and pass the view controller. Starting with the Xcode macOS Game template:

```
class Renderer: NSObject, MTKViewDelegate {

    // other properties
    
    public var graphRef: GameViewController      //. Allows access to GameViewController from elsewhere

    init?(metalKitView: MTKView, graphRef: GameViewController) {
        self.graphRef = graphRef
        
        // other init stuff
    }
    
    // other methods
}

class GameViewController: NSViewController {

    // properties

    override func viewDidLoad() {
    
        // other stuff

        guard let newRenderer = Renderer(metalKitView: mtkView, graphRef: self) else {
            print("Renderer cannot be initialized")
            return
        }

        // other renderer stuff

    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks you so much!! It finally works! (Now I need to study the changes and fully understand why)